# jQuery datatables wrong get column in drag and drop

Tags: jquery, datatables

in datatables i want to find first column when dragging row and find first column in dropping row. this below code wrong result in drag and drop rows, please help me for change thst

```
var startPosition;
var endPosition;
var old;
var newc ;
$("#example tbody").sortable({
cursor: "move",
start:function(event, ui){
    var nTds = $('td', this);
        old = $(nTds[0]).text() ;
},
update: function(event, ui) {
  endPosition = ui.item.prevAll().length + 1;
  var newc = ui.item.context.children[0].innerHTML;

  alert('old: ' + old + ' newc: ' + newc);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all `td` of first column

```
var nTds = $('tr td:first', this);
```

Comment: i can get that, that return wrong result in drag and drop, your code not work correctly for me